# perl remote execution error

Tags: linux, perl, ssh, perl-module

In the code below I am trying to clone a git repository to another machine using a Perl script.

If I print `$output`, I am getting all the login messages i.e, the contents of `/etc/motd/`, but not the actual command output.

How to resolve this issue? Am I doing something wrong in the execution of the ssh command?

```
    sub myexec_remote    
    {
       my($cmd, $hostname, $filename) = @_;

       my $stdout = $stderr = $exit= "";
       my ($output) = `ssh $hostname $cmd 2>&1`;
       ## this is the command i.e, executed
       ##command is  ssh 111.22.11.32 "git clone --bare gt@l.com:/nfs/git/ /nfs/new123/"
       $exit = $?;
       if (defined $output)
       {
       open(MYOUTFILE, ">$filename");
       print MYOUTFILE "$output";
       close(MYOUTFILE);
       }

    }
```

I am using the backticks because sometimes ssh is done *without passwordless* and I have seen that the NET:SSH module doesn't support it...

Comment: Without passwordless? With a password, or without a password (= passwordless)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is because you use the [backticks operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) **in a list context**:

```
my ($output) = `ssh $hostname $cmd 2>&1`;
```

When called in list context, backticks will return a list of lines. You only capture the first line, and put it in `$output`. The other lines are ignored. From `perldoc perlop`:

> In scalar context, it comes back as a single (potentially multi-line)
>   string, or undef if the command failed. In list context, returns a
>   list of lines (however you've defined lines with $/ or
>   $INPUT_RECORD_SEPARATOR), or an empty list if the command failed.

#### Solution:

```
1. my $output = `ssh $hostname $cmd 2>&1`;
```

Calling backticks in scalar context will cause $output to be a multiline string.

```
2. my @output = `ssh $hostname $cmd 2>&1`;
```

You can call backticks fine in array context, but you'll have to print the entire array to the `MYOUTPUTFILE` later on

#### Other comments:

*These are not part of the solution. The solution itself should be enough to fix your bug. However, they can decrease the risk of bugs, and increase your Perl knowledge.*

1. Try using the three-argument version of open, instead of your two-argument with a global, and catch the error when the file could not be opened:

   `open(my $handle, '>', $filename) or die "Unable to open file, $!";`
2. Many people decide to use  [IPC::System::Simple](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aSystem%3a%3aSimple) instead of backticks, because you have more information when something goes wrong and you can avoid the shell.
3. Another option is [IPC::Open3](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aOpen3), which even lets you capture STDOUT, STDERR and the exitcode easily. It is a bit harder to use though.

Comment: Re: "but according to the docs, $output will always be defined if the command ran". No, the docs simply say it "returns a list of lines" when there is no error. It doesn't say there will be at least one line, so the original code's `$output` could be undefined. Of course, it's a different story in scalar context.

Answer (score 0):

use [Net::OpenSSH](https://metacpan.org/module/Net%3a%3aOpenSSH):

```
use Net::OpenSSH;
my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, user => $user, password => $password);
my $output = $ssh->capture($cmd);
```